# Implementing a config file on a GUI with Tkinter | Python

Tags: python, tkinter, config, toml

I'm Writing a user friendly GUI for editing the Config file of an .exe file.

The config file is called xenia.config.toml

Users can change the config manually

What this program essentially does is that it just rewrites the configs values.

This is a Simple summary of the my code:

```
import toml
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Xenia Config Editor")
root.geometry("600x400")
readconfig = open("xenia.config.toml", "r")
dict = toml.load(readconfig, _dict=dict)


#Functions
def vsync_func():
    section = dict['GPU']

    if (vsync.get() == 1):
        section['vsync'] = 'true'
    elif (vsync.get() == 0):
        section['vsync'] = 'false'
def apply():
    with open('xenia.config.toml.tmp', 'w') as f:
        new_toml_string = toml.dump(dict, f)


#Variables
vsync = IntVar()
section = dict['GPU']
if section['vsync'] == 'true':
    vsync.set(1)
elif section['vsync'] == 'false':
    vsync.set(0)

# Checkboxes
vsync_checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Vsync", variable=vsync, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=vsync_func)
vsync_checkbox.pack()


#Buttons
applyButton = Button(root, text="Save The Config", command=apply).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that I want the python code to get the value of vsynce in the config (It's either true, or false) and return it in the check box.

as you can see I did this:

```
vsync = IntVar()
section = dict['GPU']
if section['vsync'] == 'true':
    vsync.set(1)
elif section['vsync'] == 'false':
    vsync.set(0)
```

But it didn't work
I want it to basically get the vsync value from the start, and implement it on the check box (if vsync has the value of true in the config, then check box should be checked and vise versa)

But all I can do is to change config by checking/unchecking the check box, I want to be able to do the reverse too.

Comment: The TOML loader converts the string 'true' in your config file to a logical value. Your `if` should be: `if section['vsync'] == True:` or, more simply, `if section['vsync']:`. And your `elif` should be just an `else`.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and I got this error:
`if section['vsync'] == True:
    vsync.set(1)
else section['vsync'] == False:
    vsync.set(0)`

I'm a little suspicions that TOML loader really changers the true in the config to a logical value, or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Use `vsync.set(1 if section['vsync'] else 0)`.

Comment: @captainkarma, which error did you get?

Comment: Or simply `vsync.set(int(section['vsync']))`.

Comment: @nonDucor     `else section['vsync'] == False:
         ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expected ':'`

Comment: You mean `vsync.set(1 if section['vsync'] == 'true' else 0)` ??
because section['vsync'] prints out the true/false and I should specify which one is it, if true, then set the value to 1, and so on.
I did this and nothing happened. @acw1668

Comment: @nonDucor My bad, It was something I did wrong, What you said works, thanks a lot man!

Comment: @nonDucor I just have a small question, What about other values that are not true/false (like a custom string that the developer made for the value for key = value)

Can I use the == 'string' in this situation?

Comment: @captainkarma, you should. A good way to learn what is happening is just to create a file with several cases, load it in a terminal (e.g. ipython or a notebook) and inspect what each keyword gets translated to. And have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/uiri/toml), it has some good examples.

Comment: Also, @acw1668 proposal of using `vsync.set(1 if section['vsync'] else 0)` is the more idiomatic way of doing what you want. You may find it a bit difficult to understand as a beginner but you'll get used to it.